# Getting the Glyph Name from a TTF or OTF font file

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, truetype

Hi anyone know how to get the Glyph Name from a TTF or OFT font file from C#, I'm willing to parse the file directly to get them if necessary? I found this post here [Access opentype glyph names from WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161631/access-opentype-glyph-names-from-wpf) but it got no answer.

P.S. I have created the font myself and am creating an program to create a CSS (LESS or SASS) file to use the Glyphs I have made easily in web pages like Bootstrap or FontAwesome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TrueType-based fonts (.TTF files), you can try parsing [the 'post' table](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/post.htm). It's fairly easy to figure out. *But*, only format 2.0 explicitly stores glyph names. If the post table is format 3.0, there are no glyph names stored (there are a couple of other formats defined, but fonts using them are very, very rare). In that case, your only option is to back-track using Unicode values from the 'cmap'...there are some [standard references for Unicode-to-glyph names](https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/agl-aglfn/blob/master/aglfn.txt) that may be useful.

For CFF-based fonts (.OTF files), glyph names are stored inside of [the 'CFF ' table](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/0/1/801a191c-029d-4af3-9642-555f6fe514ee/cff.pdf). That's a bit trickier to parse, but if you're only looking for the glyph name references it shouldn't be too difficult to figure out.

Comment: In this instance I have created the Font and have a TTF and OTF version and looking at a hex dump I can see the glyph names. I really just want to automate a tedious process (very tedious if you have thousands of glyphs) so I deliberately saved the Glyph names hoping that I would be able to get access to them to automate the creation of the style sheets to make them useful to all. So I will have a look and see if I can manage it, I was really hoping that there would be a .Net library I could use. :(

Comment: You mentioned that you were "willing to parse the file directly" which is why I posted the links for the data structures in question. For the 'post' table in particular, it's really not too difficult to figure out. The CFF table is only a little trickier to get to the name strings. The only additional thing you'll need to know is how to read the file's table directory in order to locate the tables within the file. That's also pretty straightforward, see http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm under 'Organization of an OpenType font'.

Comment: The question asks about _glyph names_, which are not stored in the `name` table. But since you raise the issue, I'll clarify my answer to make obvious that I'm talking about _glyph names_, not general font name strings (which _are_ stored in the `name` table).

Comment: Sorry to revive this old thread but how should I be able to access the post table via C#? I can't even get any useful results from google for this particular case.

Comment: Christoph Mett , see https://github.com/LayoutFarm/Typography